# python dictionary datetime as key, keyError

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary, keyerror

I'm trying to run a Python script using cron in Linux, which should construct a dictionary of data. I'm attempting to use `datetime().now().time()`as keys in the dictionary, but it seems to raise an error.

Can't the `datetime` type be used as a dictionary key in Python? If that is the case, what are my alternatives?

*Code:*

```
time_now = dt.datetime.now().time()
date_today = dt.datetime.now().date()
usage_dict_hourly = {}
date_wise_dict = {}

def constructing_dict(data_int):
    date_wise_dict[usage_dict_hourly[time_now]] = data_int
    print date_wise_dict
```

*Error:*

```
<ipython-input-9-ef6a500cc71b> in constructing_dict(data_int)
     36 
     37 def constructing_dict(data_int):
---> 38     date_wise_dict[usage_dict_hourly[time_now]] = data_int
     39     print date_wise_dict
     40 

KeyError: datetime.time(22, 40, 33, 746509)
```

Comment: You didn't define `usage_dict_hourly` in your example, and if you meant `usage_hourly_dict`, you didn't ever put anything in it.  No wonder it can't find the key if there aren't any keys at all.

Comment: It might be worth adding a few comments to your code. Apart from being good practice, this will be useful for us now and you/whoever else looks at this in the future. It's not clear what `date_wise_dict` and `useage_dict_hourly` are supposed to contain.

Comment: You are correct. That's a typo I committed that while I was typing here. But it doesn't solve the error.

Comment: Despite the typo, as @zondo stated your error was caused because `usage_dict_hourly` is empty, so there is nothing to be found there. It was not caused by the key type as datetime. >> *To be used as a dictionary key, an object must support the hash function (e.g. through \_\_hash\_\_), equality comparison (e.g. through \_\_eq\_\_ or \_\_cmp\_\_)* (Source: [DictionaryKeys](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys))

Answer (score 12):

Answering your question about datetime as a dictionary key:

Yes, time object of datetime can be used as dictionary key.

Conditions to use an object as a dictionary key:

> To be used as a dictionary key, an object must support the hash function (e.g. through `__hash__`), equality comparison (e.g. through `__eq__` or `__cmp__`)(...)

(Source: [DictionaryKeys](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys))

datetime support for cited conditions:

> Supported operations:
>
> ...
>
> - hash, use as dict key

(Source: [datetime - time Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects))

However, you are getting this exception because dict `usage_dict_hourly`  is empty.

`usage_dict_hourly` is initiated with `{}`. So, when you try to look for the element with key `time_now` in your function `constructing_dict`, it raises `KeyError` exception, because that key has not been found.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually setting `useage_dict_hourly` to any value that way, that's your error.
You should ideally do something like:

```
useage_dict_hourly[time_now] = None
date_wise_dict[useage_dict_hourly[time_now]] = data_int
```

Or, better yet, just use datetime.datetime.now() as the key:

```
datetime_wise_date[datetime.datetime.now()] = data_int.
```

This way, there is no possibility of clashes in the value (which is possible - though unlikely - for useage_dict_hourly)