# How to access dictionary when index is datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

I have multiple csv-files each containing two columns. The first contains the timestamp and the second column contains a measurement value.

Lets assume the csv-file looks like this:

```
Date,Temperature (Celsius)
2018-07-24T20:45:31,28.86
2018-07-24T20:35:31,29.06
2018-07-24T20:25:31,29.19
2018-07-24T20:15:32,29.31
2018-07-24T20:05:31,29.48
2018-07-24T19:55:31,29.58
2018-07-24T19:45:31,29.82
2018-07-24T19:35:32,30.32
2018-07-24T19:25:31,31.00
```

and I import it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv-file, sep=',', header = 0, usecols=[0, 1], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)
dd = df.set_index('Date').T.to_dict()
```

I thought this would be convenient later, when I would search for the same key (same timestamp) in multiple files in order to merge them.
However I cannot access the dictionary. The keys are recognised as timestamp.

```
dd.keys()

dict_keys([Timestamp('2018-07-24 20:45:31'), Timestamp('2018-07-24 20:35:31'), Timestamp('2018-07-24 20:25:31'), Timestamp('2018-07-24 20:15:32'), Timestamp('2018-07-24 20:05:31'), Timestamp('2018-07-24 19:55:31'), Timestamp('2018-07-24 19:45:31'), Timestamp('2018-07-24 19:35:32'), Timestamp('2018-07-24 19:25:31')])
```

How do I access the values?

```
dd["2018-07-24 20:45:31"]["Temperature (Celsius)"]
```

does not work, so I tried

```
dd[Timestamp("2018-07-24 20:45:31")]["Temperature (Celsius)"]
```

which does not work either.

I was wondering if it might be forbidden to use a timestamp as a key, but if not, than how do I access my data?

Comment: I guess your problem is already solved.
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946387/python-dictionary-datetime-as-key-keyerror) out.

Comment: I found this question as well, but I could not figure out how I access the data. Could you help me out here? How do I read out the temperature at this (2018-07-24 20:45:31) point in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the `Timestamp` keys you see are instances of `pandas.Timestamp`. You should pass your keys with `pd.Timestamp`, like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    'file.csv', sep=',', header = 0, usecols=[0, 1], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True
)
dd = df.set_index('Date').T.to_dict()

print(dd[pd.Timestamp('2018-07-24 20:45:31')]['Temperature (Celsius)']) # prints 28.86
```

Comment:  thanks, I did check whether the conversion preserves it, but I did not think about using it when looking through a dictionary. SOLVED.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add a `from pandas import Timestamp` and your code will work.

Comment: I see, I was under the impression that the "Timestamp" was somehow universal not tied to pandas. Thanks for pointing that out.